# GPIO.wait_for_edge and signal.signal()

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, interrupts, signal

I have the below sample code that is trying to implement a safe shutdown mechanism ( yet to fully implement)

For some reason, I am not able to catch any signals using the registered signal handlers. I am not an expert and have tried googling and not much turned up.

On the other hand, If I comment out the line 
"GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)" I am able to catch all the signals successfully. 
I feel I am missing a crucial concept here and there is a bug in this code but not able to figure out the same.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

```
import os, time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import signal


def receive_signal(signal, frame):
    # Trying to catch USR# Signals here.
    print('Received:', signal)

def handleSIGKILL(signal, frame):
    # Handle standard Signals here - only log as of now.
    with open("$HOME/tmp/sig.log", "a") as sig_file:
         print >> sig_file, time.ctime(), "::Caught - Signal:", signal
    GPIO.cleanup()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# GPIO 23 set up as input. It is pulled up to stop false signals
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def createDaemon():
  """
      Service/Daemon that will execute a task
  """

  try:
    # Store the Fork PID
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid > 0:
      print 'PID: %d' % pid
      # Open the file in write mode
      with open("$HOME/tmp/gpio_pid_log.log", "a") as pid_log_file:
           print >> pid_log_file, time.ctime(),"::PID: ", pid
      os._exit(0)

  except OSError, error:
    print 'Unable to fork. Error: %d (%s)' % (error.errno, error.strerror)
    os._exit(1)

  doTask()
def doTask():
  """
      A task that will be a daemon
  """
  print "\n"

  print "Registering handler for:SIGTERM\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handleSIGKILL)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGINT\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handleSIGKILL)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGHUP\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handleSIGKILL)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGUSR1\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGUSR2\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)

  # Open the file in write mode
  with open("$HOME/tmp/gpio_detection.log", "a") as gpio_file:

       # Start the write
       while True:
         GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
         print >> gpio_file, time.ctime(), "::Falling edge detected.\n"
         gpio_file.flush()
         time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Create the Daemon
  createDaemon()
```

Answer (score 1):

After changing the doTask function from

From:

```
def doTask():
  """
      A task that will be a daemon
  """
  print "\n"

  print "Registering handler for:SIGTERM\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handleSIGKILL)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGINT\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handleSIGKILL)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGHUP\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handleSIGKILL)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGUSR1\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
  print "Registering handler for:SIGUSR2\n"
  signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)

  # Open the file in write mode
  with open("$HOME/tmp/gpio_detection.log", "a") as gpio_file:

       # Start the write
       while True:
         GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
         print >> gpio_file, time.ctime(), "::Falling edge detected.\n"
         gpio_file.flush()
         time.sleep(2)
```

To:

```
    def doTask():
      """
          A task that will be a daemon
      """
      print "\n"

      print "Registering handler for:SIGTERM\n"
      signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handleSIGKILL)
      print "Registering handler for:SIGINT\n"
      signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handleSIGKILL)
      print "Registering handler for:SIGHUP\n"
      signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handleSIGKILL)
      print "Registering handler for:SIGUSR1\n"
      signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
      print "Registering handler for:SIGUSR2\n"
      signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)

  try:
      # GPIO 23 set up as input.
      GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
      #GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
      GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
      # Start the write
      while True:
          if not 'event' in locals():
             print "Adding event\n"
             # GPIO add event callback
             event = GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.BOTH, 
                     callback=powerUpOrDown, bouncetime=2000)
          else:
             time.sleep(2)
  finally:
          GPIO.cleanup()
```

And defining powerUpOrDown appropriately. I was able to achieve what I wanted to. Thanks.

Comment: may I suggest: you could post `diff` output instead of the original code and the changed code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Usage

Answer (score 0):

Your `GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)` call blocks execution until defined pin change occurs. Commenting that out doesn't mean you are detecting desired signals, instead, your endless loop just runs through and ignores any external signals, which gives you a false 'detection' every 2 seconds (as of `time.sleep(2)`). See the [documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) for reference.

If you are sure that the actual pin change (pulling pin 23 LOW externally) does occur, I suggest double checking that the pin layout you specified by `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` is indeed aligned with your actual hardware setup.

From the docs:

> There are two ways of numbering the IO pins on a Raspberry Pi within RPi.GPIO. The first is using the BOARD numbering system. This refers to the pin numbers on the P1 header of the Raspberry Pi board. The advantage of using this numbering system is that your hardware will always work, regardless of the board revision of the RPi. You will not need to rewire your connector or change your code. 
>   The second numbering system is the BCM numbers. This is a lower level way of working - it refers to the channel numbers on the Broadcom SOC. You have to always work with a diagram of which channel number goes to which pin on the RPi board. Your script could break between revisions of Raspberry Pi boards.

In case the blocking behaviour is not what you wanted in the first place, the documentation also offers different change detection methods like callbacks, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response ; Yes, was exploring  - GPIO.add_event_detect   with the callback.

Also, when I meant commenting out "worked", the signal handling part worked, not my main goal of capturing GPIO edge event. I should have been more clear-er in my articulation.

Comment: I guessed that, hence the suggestion to check your pin layout.